# How to change a value in an association in a list for Cellular Automata project?

Tags: warning-messages, cellular-automata

I'm trying to change a value in an association in a list. This is part of a larger project of creating a function that can mutate a 2D Cellular Automata several times to make it look like another 2D CA that the user determines. I have stored the 2D rule in a list which contains the association between 1 and another list and 0 and another list. Here's an example rule `{1 -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, 0 -> {{1, 0}, {0, 0}}}`. I want to change the 1's and 0's of the rule, to 'mutate' it and I did it using this code in this function,

```
twoDmutate[rule1_, mprob_] :=
 Do[
  rule1[[i, 2, j, k]] = 2
  , {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}, {k, 1, 2}
  ]
(*Shows the rule post-mutation*)
twoDmutate[twoDinitialrule, twoDmutationProbability]
```

, but when I do this, I get this error `"Set: {1->{{1,1},{0,0}},0->{{1,1},{0,1}}} in the part assignment is not a symbol"`. Can someone explain what this error means, and how I need to fix it to so that I can change the 1's and 0's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of evaluation for the expression

```
First[twoDinitialrule][[2]][[1]][[1]]
```

starts by evaluating `First[twoDinitialrule]`. Assuming that your `twoDinitialrule` is the example you provided,

```
twoDinitialrule = {1 -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, 0 -> {{1, 0}, {0, 0}}}
```

then `First[twoDinitialrule]` evaluates to `1 -> {{z, 0}, {0, 0}}`. That's not a symbol and so you can't do any assignment to its parts. The special form that allows you to mutate the OwnValues of symbols with `Set` is `Part`:

```
twoDinitialrule[[1, 2, 1, 1]] = 999
```

That `Set` expression will return just the `999`, but the side effect will be to mutate `twoDinitialrule`:

```
twoDinitialrule
(* {1 -> {{999, 0}, {0, 0}}, 0 -> {{1, 0}, {0, 0}}} *)
```

#### Update

Actually, I guess from the message, the problem isn't that `First[twoDinitialrule]` doesn't evaluate to a symbol, but that `Set` "sees" that you're trying to mutate something using the `Part` form, but when it inspects the head, it sees something that's not a symbol.

Comment: This works when I run it out of the function but inside the function it doesn't work

Comment: Well, that function wasn't there before. But anyway, yeah, that won't work, because `rule1` gets bound to the value you pass in, which again, is evaluated to the whole expression of a list of rules, not just a symbol.

Comment: To make that work, you're going to need to use some sort of `Hold*` property and make sure you only pass symbols in to the function to be bound to `rule1`.

Comment: It looks like @vindobona already showed you that.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `HoldFirst` attribute might help:

```
ClearAll[rule, mutate];
rule = {1 -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, 0 -> {{1, 0}, {0, 0}}};

SetAttributes[mutate, HoldFirst]
mutate[rule1_] := Do[rule1[[i, 2, j, k]] = 2, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}, {k, 1, 2}]

mutate[rule];
rule
```

> `{1 -> {{2, 2}, {2, 2}}, 0 -> {{2, 2}, {2, 2}}}`